# MongoDB documents of nexted arrays vs dictionaries

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I've started logging all the DNS queries from my network, and am wondering which would be the best storage mechanism.

Currently I'm using MySQL, but querying it is a bit cumbersome (a bit slow due to JOINS) and the storage is pretty bloated, so I've changed the tabular data layout from

```
2014-10-13T08:28:35.570+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 72.21.210.52 | device-metrics-us.amazon.com

2014-10-13T08:28:44.522+0200 | 192.168.5.9 | CNAME | googleapis.l.google.com | www.googleapis.com
2014-10-13T08:28:44.522+0200 | 192.168.5.9 | A | 74.125.29.95 | googleapis.l.google.com

2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | CNAME | android.l.google.com | android.clients.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.160 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.165 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.166 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.168 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.162 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.169 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.163 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.164 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.174 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.161 | android.l.google.com
2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200 | 192.168.5.5 | A | 74.125.226.167 | android.l.google.com
```

to a NOSQL-friendly format

```
["2014-10-13T08:28:35.570+0200", "Mon 08:28", "192.168.5.5", ["device-metrics-us.amazon.com"], ["72.21.210.52"]],
["2014-10-13T08:28:44.522+0200", "Mon 08:28", "192.168.5.9", ["www.googleapis.com", "googleapis.l.google.com"], ["74.125.29.95"]],
["2014-10-13T08:28:45.618+0200", "Mon 08:28", "192.168.5.5", ["android.clients.google.com", "android.l.google.com"], ["74.125.226.160", "74.125.226.165", "74.125.226.166", "74.125.226.168", "74.125.226.162", "74.125.226.169", "74.125.226.163", "74.125.226.164", "74.125.226.174", "74.125.226.161", "74.125.226.167"]],
```

I've got these fixed indices:

0: timestamp,

1: more readable timestamp

2: source of the query

3: an array where the first element is the requested dns name, and subsequent elements are CNAMEs

4: an array of the returned IP addresses

Since all this stuff will also be held in memory, and the structure won't change, I thought I skip the keys in order to save RAM (the storage server is already maxing out the RAM usage).

Is this OK? Or do I have a real benefit of adding keys, like so (or even one single char as the key):

```
{"timestamp": "2014-10-13T08:28:35.570+0200", "nice": "Mon 08:28", "ip": "192.168.5.5", "query":["device-metrics-us.amazon.com"], "result":["72.21.210.52"]},
```

I'd really prefer to have raw arrays.

I will be querying often for an IP address in the result list and expect to get the initial query as a result, limiting by time and device (Oth and 2nd field)

As of now, I'm planning to use MongoDB.

Any recommendations on the data format in order to maximize efficiency (RAM and speed) and queryability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write some comments here just for your reference:

- Array of BSON is actually a document structure (different data type of course). For example, [1, 2, 3] == `{"0":1, "1":1, "2":3}` [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html);
- Index is created upon key(s), using certain key to narrow data range is helpful to improve query performance. So with key is necessary for your structure.
- As you want to save memory extremely, create keys with one character for each.

So, structure your provide

```
{"timestamp": "2014-10-13T08:28:35.570+0200", "nice": "Mon 08:28", "ip": "192.168.5.5", "query":["device-metrics-us.amazon.com"], "result":["72.21.210.52"]}
```

is better and better.

Comment: OK, thanks, I also noticed that I'm unable to insert plain arrays.

Comment: Oh man, it's a dream to query on that data in comparison to SQL.

Comment: @DanielF, what happened to you?

Comment: That was in Python with pymongo. I got an exception, the same one one gets when you try to insert a string instead of an object, can't remember the exact error message.